# Conver Python to html using Django

Tags: python, html, django, google-maps-api-3, web-deployment

I have a Python program for customers to query price. Each time a customer can input some necessary information, the program will calculate and return the price to customer. Note: during the calculation process, the program also need to query a third party map service web API to get some information (such as google map API or other similar service).

I have a website developed using web development tools such Wix, Strikingly. It offers a capability to customize a web page by simply input a block of HTML codes. So, I want to study the possibility of using Django to convent my python program into HTML (incl. add some user interface such as text box and button), which can then be pasted into the website to form a unique webpage.

I am not sure if it is doable? Especially, the part of connecting third party map service API. Would Django be able to convert this part automatically to HTML as well? (how does it deal with API key and connection).

Comment: `HTML` will be useless without Python/Django code. And as I know `Wix, Strikingly` can't run Python/Django

Comment: I have the python code, but currently can only run on my computer.

Comment: better find server which can run Django (like [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) and forget `Wix, Strikingly`. If you see some nice HTML on `Wix, Strikingly` then save page in file and copy HTML from this file to your project - but it may need some changes.

Comment: @furas thanks. as suggested above, does pythonanywhere.com free version support my python program to connect with other API to get data?

Comment: see [Whitelisted sites for free users: PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/)

Answer (score 1):

Python itself runs only on the console, and is meant to be the backend in site development, whereas HTML is meant only to be the frontend, so no calculation or data fetching. Wix is a frontend tool with some content management that offers customization but still in the frontends (html/css), and there's nothing more you could do with the content management other than using the built in table like feature. Trying to use the html generated by wix will be so much pain due to its css name optimization and making it quite unscalable.

 
If you don't wish to learn frontend building at all then you could look up other html generator tool for the frontend codes. From there, django itself is capable of building the entire website, using the html you generated as template, and passing the data you've computed into the templates. That's what Django is meant to do. In this case you would need to learn Django itself, which I would recommend if you intend to showcase your project as an interactive program rather just console logs.

Other alternatives include converting your python codes into javascript, which is capable of doing calculations and fetching from APIs, and you can include the javascript code directly in HTML with the  tag.

Comment: thanks. as suggested above, does pythonanywhere.com free version support my python program to connect with other API to get data?